# When compressing files (zip, tar, ect...) in SSH what determines the 'sort order' in which files are compressed?

Tags: sorting, tar

Consider the following command run on a folder with 2TB of recursive folders and files in it.

`tar -cvzf _backup.tar.gz /home/wwwsite/public_html`

Consider that the folder being compressed  is full of sub-folders (with hundreds of sub folders and files in them) and a naming convention that is random, but sequential, short example:

```
/17688EE/
/18503HH/
/19600SL/
/20659CS/
```

Consider that there are 10,000+ folders between each block (17000 block, then 18000 block, ect...). Naming Convention: Number 00000 + Letter A-Z, (ie: 17000AZ-17000ZA) so the folders can easily be sorted by name.

Consider that the tar command is being run in a screen with verbose output in order to check on the "progress" of that command.

```
screen -S compress
```

In theory, I had assumed I could simply look at the output of that screen, but I notice that the TARBALL *does not seem to be compressing the folder in either the order they were created, nor sort them based on the name of the folder*.

**Therefore my question is two fold:**

Other than looking at the verbose output of the TARBALL and guessing;

1. Is there any where to find out how long the compression process will take to complete? (such as adding a -tack command onto the TAR to show estimated time to completion, something similar to the % complete of an SCP command)
2. In what order does the TAR command decide to compress the folders? ( and is there a way to tell the command to "sort by" date/name during compression?)

To elaborate, after 20 min of waiting for the 17001AA-to-AZ block to compress I would figure next up would be the 17001BA-to-BZ block, but this is not the case, the verbose output shows what seem to be randomly grabbing folders without sorting by name nor date)

**Simply put: What determines the sort order during compression?**

Comment: I assume that tar reads the dirs and files in the order they are stored on the disk.

Comment: Interesting... so in theory if I defrag that disk then would the folders end up being stored in a "human readable" order?

Comment: Assuming the filesystem you are using actually supports defragmentation, you are at the mercy of how that filesystem is implemented. It may not reorder the directory entries at all.

What platform are you running?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give tar a list of directory names, the order of the entries in the tar file will match the order that [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) returns filenames from the filesystem. The fact that you are compressing the tar file has no bearing on the order.

Here is a quick example to illustrate what happens on a Linux ext4 filesystem. Other filesystems may behave differently.

First create a new directory with three files, `a1`, `a2` and `a3`

```
$ mkdir fred
$ cd fred
$ touch a1 a2 a3
```

Now lets see the order that [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) returns the files. The `-U` option will make `ls` return the filenames unsorted in the order they are stored in the directory.

```
$ ls -U
a3  a1  a2
```

As you can see, on my Linux setup the files are returned in an apparently random order.

Now stick the files in a tar file. Note I'm giving tar a directory name for the input file ("`.`" in this instance) to make sure it has to call [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) behind the scenes.

```
$ tar cf xxx.tar .
```

And finally, lets see the order that tar has stored the files.

```
$ tar tf xxx.tar 
./
./a3
./a1
./a2
```

The order of the files `a1`, `a2` and `a3` matches the order that [readdir](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) returned the filenames from the filesystem. The `.` filename is present because it was explicitly included on the command line passed to tar.

If you want to force an order you will have to give tar a sorted list of filenames. The example below shows how to get tar to read the list of filenames from stdin, using the `-T -` command line option.

```
$ ls a* | tar  cvf yyy.tar -T -
a1
a2
a3
```

In this toy example the list of filenames will be automatically sorted because the shell sorts the filenames that match the wildcard  `a*`.

And just to confirm, this is what is in the tar file.

```
$ tar tf yyy.tar 
a1
a2
a3
```

In your use-case a combination of the `find` and `sort` commands piped into `tar` should allow you to create a sorted tar file with as many entries as you like.

Something like this as a starting point.

```
find | sort | tar -cvzf _backup.tar.gz -T -
```

Comment: thank you. I see... this makes total sense and explains why I got the results I did.

Comment: Side note: to solve the problem of "guessing" time to completion I manually moved 1000 folders of various sizes into a staging directory, compressed it and estimated time to completion for the other 500,000 folders...